# Holo theme in android makes application stop 'unfortunately'

Tags: android, xml, styles, themes

so I'm trying to style my application, and I've run into problems when using the Holo theme. I have no intrest in earlier versions of android, so I'don't want to use AppCompat. 
To do my error checking I have created an empty app with one blank activity. This is my styles.xml:

```
    <resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme_ActionBarTheme</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme_ActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/light_green</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/AppTheme_ActionBarTheme_Text</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme_ActionBarTheme_Text" parent="AppTheme_ActionBarTheme">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/light</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

and this is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.fokamb.chmielowskim.fokamb" >
    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="15"  android:minSdkVersion="14"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"

        android:label="@string/app_name"

        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

        >

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/main_act_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I didn't change any other files, and I tried running this app on an emulator with API level 21 and my phone with api 19. On both, i get the message "Unfortunately, FokaMB has stopped"
Even though, in the preview window in android studio the app looks the way I would've liked it to. 
So, where might be my mistake? If I use AppCompat app works fine, but im unable to change the text color of actionbar (even though the background changes). Any help would be greatly appreciated:)

Comment: Oh, I get a "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fokamb.chmielowskim.fokamb/com.fokamb.chmielowskim.fokamb.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity." error. I didn't really know logcat even existed, as im very new to java apps on android. Is there anything I can do to not to have to use AppCompat? With it I'm unable to style my app the way I would like to.